# Cannot call method 'apply' of null

Tags: javascript

Hy,
 does anyone know what's causing this error in javascript:

```
'Cannot call method 'apply' of null'
```

? Here is some part of the code:

```
this.tiles[i][j] = tile;
var self = this;
var tileOnClick = tile.onClick;
tile.onClick = function (e){

  self.handleTileClick(tile, e);
  tileOnClick.apply(tile, [e]);


  };
    grid.prototype.handleTileClick=function(tile)
 {
    if(this.selectedTile)
    {
        this.selectedTile.select(false);
    }
    _onTileClick.apply(this,[tile]);
    alert("click");
 }
```

All I need are some ideas of where to look.
The alert is executed, and I don't see why would be a pb with apply...
Thank you.

Comment: `_onTileClick` doesn't seem to exist anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your variable to the value of `tile.onClick` *before* you give that attribute a value. At the point when you assign `tileOnClick = tile.onClick`, it's null.

You need to do the assignment *after* you bind the event, or better yet, rethink how you're doing this:

```
var tileOnClick = function (e){

  self.handleTileClick(tile, e);
  tileOnClick.apply(tile, [e]);


  };

tile.onClick = tileOnClick;
```